# Tomcat. Deadlock on openJarFile. Why?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

Sometimes my server (Tomcat 8.5.15 on Ununtu server) is in a deadlock state. We got a thread dump and it turned out

Stack trace of blocked thread:

```
org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntries(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:63)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:95)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:69)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1067)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
```

Stack trace of problem thread:

```
java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166)
java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:308)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:95)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:69)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1067)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
```

At the same time, the number of open files in OS is not even close to the maximum. 
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Where is the jar-file that is accessed here located?

Comment: I don't know what jar file.
All tomcat libraries are in the lib folder.
All application libraries are in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
In general, everything is standard

Comment: Are these directories local directories or network shares or something similar. It looks like the access to the file blocks keeping `java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)` from returning. Some code in `org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet` is synchronized so you get this effect. I wouldn't call it deadlock, though, because as soon as the file access operations finishs (successfully or not doesn't matter), the other thread should happily continue.

Comment: What about the CPU usage when this happens?

Comment: CPU is almost not used

Comment: You are probably facing JAXP provider search problem, refer: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Blocked-thread-on-finding-org-apache-xerces-parsers-DOMParser-service-provider